# Detect changes in CellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an editable WPF DataGrid.
When I enter a cell in edit mode and leave it again then the `CellEditEnding` event fires. It looks like this:

```
private void MyDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
     //detect cell changes
}
```

Now this always fires, even if the cell did not change. How can I detect if a cell actually changed or not?

#### I am looking for a general approach. I do NOT want to check what column that cell belongs to and compare the cell value to the matching property in the model underneath.

Comment: are you linking the datagrid to a datasource?

Comment: No, not directly.

Comment: I have recently started using BindingList and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. This notification is very easy to set so that it is only sent if the data has changed. If this looks like something you might be interested in I will try and find the link I used to get my code working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can detect changes without comparing to the model. When I ran into this issue (and many more with wpf's default DataGrid) I made an extended DataGrid to make life easier. There are a bunch of articles online about this with great additions to the default DataGrid.

I added an event to the extended DataGrid that basically hands over all the relevant and affected data so that comparing is super easy and straight forward.

```
#region Multirow editing event =====================================================================================================================================

    public delegate void OnEditDelegate(IEnumerable<object> selectedItems, string editedColumnProperty, object newValue);
    public event OnEditDelegate OnEdit;

    private void OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.IsReadOnly)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (((Binding) ((DataGridBoundColumn) e.Column).Binding).Path.Path == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bound property is null in extendedDataGrid (OnCellEditEnding)");
            return;
        }

        string editedColumnProperty = ((Binding)((DataGridBoundColumn)e.Column).Binding).Path.Path;
        object newValue = null;
        if (e.EditingElement is TextBox editingTextBox)
        {
            newValue = editingTextBox.Text;
        }
        //object newValue = editingTextBox.Text;
        List<object> selectedItems = new List<object>();
        foreach (DataGridCellInfo info in SelectedCells)
        {
            selectedItems.Add(info.Item);
        }
        //If 2 cells of the same row are selected, the bound item gets added twice. Here we remove those duplicates. Use SelectedItems?
        selectedItems = selectedItems.Distinct().ToList();

        OnEdit?.Invoke(selectedItems, editedColumnProperty, newValue);
    }
    #endregion
```

Consume as follows:

```
 private void DataGrid_OnEdit(IEnumerable<object> selecteditems, string editedcolumnproperty, object newvalue)
 {
 }
```

You then have access to the items that were selected, know which property was updated and have the new value.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who's still looking for a simple solution. You can just do the following if you used bindings.

*Yes, you still need to compare values with the base model, but at least everything can be done in the same function.*

```
public bool Modified { get; set; }

private void DG_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Cancel)
        return;
    
    var entry = (MyType)e.Row.Item;
    var text = ((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text; // This assumes you only used DataGridTextColumn's
    switch (e.Column.DisplayIndex) // This assumes the user is not allowed to re-order columns
    {
        case 0:
            Modified |= entry.Column0 != text;
            break;
        case 1:
            Modified |= entry.Variable != text;
            break;
        case 3:
            Modified |= entry.Text != text;
            break;
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could also do everything in the model by using dependency properties.